# Encoding error due to JS Internationalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

After rails upgrade 6.0.4.1 to 6.1.4.1 the following error occurs:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error ("\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):
     13: 
     14:     <script type="text/javascript">
     15:       window.I18n = <%= current_translations.to_json.html_safe %>;
     16:     </script>

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:15
```

In the application helper the `current_translations` method is defined standard:

```
def current_translations
  @translations ||= I18n.backend.send(:translations)
  @translations[I18n.locale].with_indifferent_access
end
```

After inspecting `current_translations` (which is a `Concurrent::Hash`) it results that it contains the byte \xC3 in the `:transliterate` key

```
... :transliterate=>{:rule=>{:"\xC3\xA0"=>"a", :"\xC3\xA1"=>"a", :"\xE1\xBA\xA1"=> "a", :"\xE1\xBA\xA3"=>"a", :"\xC3\xA3"=>"a", :"\xC3\xA2"=>"a", ...
```

After further tests I could determine the error won't occur without `.to_json` i.e.

```
window.I18n = <%= current_translations %>
```

or if the `bootsnap` gem will be removed, but there are just workarounds to avoid the error.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

**UPDATE**. It seems `i18n-1.8.11` is OK, but `i18n-1.9.1` produces the error (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Comment: This `msgpack` bug could be related: https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-ruby/pull/246

Answer (score 0):

The [msgpack patch](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/issues/606#issuecomment-1024025727) works:

```
gem 'msgpack', github: 'Shopify/msgpack-ruby', branch: 'symbolize-keys-fix-encoding'
```

**UPDATE**. Final fix in gem i18n 1.10.0.